# MP3 (MPEG I) chunk decoder for Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I've been searching for a few days and trying many different libraries including PyDub, python_mp3_decoder (segmentation faults), pymad, but have had basically no luck in finding a library for Python that would allow me to decode a MP3 Stream (from a internet radio; icecast) on the fly and treat it like microphone input (e.g. PyAudio stream).

I am trying to get a stream of decoded audio to use with PyAudio for an acoustic fingerprinting project. The other catch is I cannot use PyMedia which has been suggest here on stackoverflow before since it is not supported on the Mac, nor has it been updated in more than 12 years.

Any input on how I could decode a MP3 Stream in real time in python would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247248/record-streaming-and-saving-internet-radio-in-python

Comment: @Alex thanks for the help, however the trouble here is not saving an MP3 stream. I can save a stream and then let a standard audio player play it, but I want to have these chunks in memory and then decode them in memory to a PCM array which I can then work on